# Given a $1$-form $\omega$ on $\Bbb R^n$, is there a connection whose torsion is $T(X,Y)=\omega(X)Y-\omega(Y)X$?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, connections

Consider $(R^n, g_0 )$, where $g_0$ is the Euclidean metric, and a differential $1$-form $\omega$ on $R^n$. Can this differential form define a connection on  $M=R^n$ such that its torsion is
$$T(X,Y)=\omega(X)Y-\omega(Y)X ?$$

Thanks.

Comment: The wording is a little strange---usually one would say "Suppose $g_0$ is the Riemannian metric on $\Bbb R^n$. Anyway, what is the role of the metric here? Do you also want the connection to be a metric connection for $g_0$?

Comment: question doesn't want  the connection be  metric compatible.

Comment: That's strange. There's no reason to mention the metric at all then.

Comment: Do you mean a *unique* connection? This certainly requires metric-compatibility or some similar condition.

Comment: I didn't mean unique connection.

Comment: I suggest asking that in a separate question, including the thoughts/work you have for it already.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** In a holonomic basis, the components of the torsion tensor are given by
$$T^c{}_{ab} = \Gamma^c_{ab} - \Gamma^c_{ba} ,$$
where $\Gamma_{ab}^c$ are the Christoffel symbols of the connection. Can you choose the Christoffel symbols so that the identity is satisfied? (One can even choose them so that the connection is metric.)